# ¿Como realizar un array en java y que el ciclo que recorra el arreglo y le permita al usuario reemplazar los valores impares por otro valor?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Necesito que el programa me imprima con ciclo los valores del arreglo y sus indices, solo reemplazar los valores impares por otro valor.
Necesito condicionales para determinar los valores impares.
Ejemplo:

Primer ingreso que se debe hacer en el programa:

***Reemplace el valor 17 con otro numero:
30
Reemplace el valor 15 con otro numero:
100
Reemplace el valor 13 con otro numero:
500
Reemplace el valor 11 con otro numero:
70***

Al final el programa imprime los nuevos arreglos y los demás valores que en total seria 8 valores:

```
  Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

   int [] valores = {88, 17, 98, 15, 13, 36, 40, 11};
   int [] impares = new int [valores.length];
   int pares = 0;
   
   for (int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
       
            if (valores[i]%2!=0)
                 pares += valores[i];
          
    System.out.println(i + ":" + valores[i]);
               
            System.out.println("Reemplace el valor de "+valores[i]+" con otro numero: ");
                valores[i] = lector.nextInt();
```

Final como debería de quedar el programa:

0: 88
1:30
2:98
3:100
4:500
5:36
6:40
7:70

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Solo necesito reemplazar los valores impares, y me salga con los valores pares.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner una comparación de tu salida y de la salida correcta?

Comment: Ok esta bien voy a corregirlo en la pregunta.

Comment: Claro, pero cual es el problema puntual que no pudiste corregir en tu codigo? porque tu codigo parece casi completo...

Comment: Ok voy revisar.

Comment: @gbianchi que le falta llaves a su if para que ejecute condicionalmente las últimas 4 líneas, eso es lo que está pasando solo cuando sea un índice par en vez de pedir remplazo para todos

Comment: @RuslanLópez ssssssshhhhhhhhhh que eso se soluciona depurando y siguiendo el codigo... le falta un else ;)

Comment: Si exacto solo necesito reemplazar los impares, y junto a ello al final imprimir todos.

Comment: Ok esta bien voy revisarlo con un else. :)

Comment: @JimmyRamirez yo te recomiendo que aprendas a depurar y seguir tu codigo.. de esa forma, te darias cuenta rapidamente donde esta el problema y que necesitas para solucionarlo...

Comment: @gbianchi Es que no todo el mundo sabe como hacer una prueba de escritorio, pero yo tampoco sé una manera académica de enseñar como realizarla, así que esperaré a que vea dónde poner las llaves que le faltan :P

Comment: Voy a revisarlo con el else. XD

Comment: @RuslanLópez eso es lo primero que hay que aprender.. a esta altura muchos depuramos el codigo a medida que lo vemos.. pero casi todas las ide tienen herramientas de depuracion.. y si no.. a la antigua.. con escribir a consola todo lo que pasa...

Comment: @gbianchi ya le puse tres formas de analizar su programa: diagrama de flujo, depurador y prueba de escritorio, si conoces alguna más me interesaría saberla :)

Comment: @RuslanLópez es una excelente respuesta para una pregunta canonica.. no para esta, porque nadie la va a encontrar aca.. pensemos mejor en sacarla de aca y hacerla canonica...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Forma teórica: el diagrama de flujo

Lo primero es analizar tu programa. Como afortunadamente no usas POO, se puede modelar el la ejecución mediante mediante un **diagrama de flujo** como el siguiente de [code2flow](https://app.code2flow.com/):

[image: diagrama de flujo actual]

Como verás hay un problema en la parte interna del ciclo, que deberemos corregir para que nos dé el siguiente ciclo

[image: diagrama de flujo corregido]

### modo interactivo: el depurador

Como no todos los programas son imperativos te recomiendo usar un **depurador**, como por ejemplo el [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_debugger). Puedes hallar un pequeño manual en inglés [aquí](https://www.onlinegdb.com/blog/brief-guide-on-how-to-use-onlinegdb-debugger/).

En el manual básicamente te explica como poner un *breakpoint*.

[image: como se ve la depuración cuando llega a un breakpoint]

Los depuradores tradicionalmente paran la ejecución y para continuarla deberemos usar los botones de la interfaz

[image: botones para depurar]

Dichos botones son:

- continuar (sigue corriendo normalmente el programa)
- saltarse el paso (ejecuta el sigiuente paso sin entrar en los detalles de los subpasos)
- entrar en el siguiente paso (ejecuta el sigiuente paso entrando al primer paso de los subpasos que requiera)
- salir del paso actual (para ejecutar lo que falta de los subpasos y regresar al paso superior que lo llamó)

Algunos depuradores también tienen una pila de llamadas en la que paarecen cada una de las funciones que se han llamado en órden

[image: pila de llamadas]

Muchos depuradores también te muestran una lista de las variables locales, es decir de las variables del método actual y sus valores en cada momento.

[image: variables locales]

Finalmente te recomiendo usar `java.utils.Arrays` y su método `toString(tuArreglo)` para imprimir una versión amigable del arreglo en consola de manera que tu salida se vea algo así:

[image: salida en el onlinegdb]

### ¿Y que pasa si todo eso me da flojera?

Bueno si eres vieja escuela y tu programa no es tan grande puedes usar la vieja y confiable **prueba de escritorio**, que es una tablita en la que vas a poner en una columna las instrucciones y en las demás cada variable que manejes y vas a poner el valor de cada variable por cada instrucción, una vez que hayas acabado tu programa puedes verificar hasta que instrucción tu programa falló.

Una tablita de prueba de escritorio se ve algo así:

[image: Prueba de escritorio]

Comment: Excelente gracias voy a revisarlo.

Comment: y agregaria que casi todas las ides tienen metodos de depuracion internos, mucho mejores que los online...