# Consulta para este problema básico de Java

Tags: java

Estaba practicando en Java y entonces cuando quería simular que un auto se apague dos veces, me sale el mismo mensaje en la consola, que debería cambiar para que funcione?

```
public class JavaPractica {

  public static void main(String args[]) {    

  auto ferrari = new auto();
  ferrari.apagar();
  ferrari.apagar();
  }}
```

```
    public class auto {

    boolean estado = false;
    
    public auto(){
        System.out.println("se creo un objeto de tipo auto");
    }
    
    public void apagar (){
         if(estado == true){
            System.out.println("el vehiculo se apago");
            estado = false;
             
         }else{
             System.out.println("el vehiculo ya esta apagado");
         }}
```

```
se creo un objeto de tipo auto
el vehiculo se apago
el vehiculo se apago
```

Comment: nunca prendiste tu auto, es de esperarse la salida.

Comment: Te recomienod revisar mi respuesta a esta otra pregunta para que aprendas como analizar tu programa por tí mismo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/400434/342

Comment: La salida que has puesto es inconsistente con tu código, por lo tanto el problema no se puede reproducir, puedes describir mejor el problema?

Answer (score 0):

para empezar tienes una clase dentro de otra, esto no se suele usar en este tipo de casos, las clases internas se usan mas que nada para eventos, por lógica de orientación a objetos no tiene ningún sentido que la clase auto este dentro de la clase JavaPractica, es mejor practica agregar esta clase en otro archivo o en el mismo pero fuera de la clase JavaPractica.

La razón por la que aparece "el vehículo ya esta apagado" 2 veces es que el condicional pregunta ¿el estado es true? y responde "no, es false" por esa razón se va al else e imprime por primera vez el vehículo ya esta apagado, la variable estado a todo esto sigue en false por lo que al llamar otra vez el mismo método sucede lo mismo, reacciona igual.

Es decir hay un error en el planteo, lo que deberías hacer es INICIALIZAR EL ATRIBUTO ESTADO EN TRUE de modo que la primera vez que se invoque el método apagar "mostrara el vehículo se apago" y en la segunda mostrará "el vehículo ya esta apagado" PORQUE AL INICIAR EL OBJETO FERRARI ESTE YA ESTARÍA ENCENDIDO.

```
boolean estado = true;
```